# Format string with all elements of a list

Tags: python, string, list, string-formatting

```
words = ['John', 'nice', 'skateboarding']
statement = "%s you are so %s at %s" % w for w in words
```

produces

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
statement = "%s you are so %s at %s" % w for w in words
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong here? The assumption is: len(words) == number of '%s' in statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> statement = "%s you are so %s at %s" % tuple(words)
'John you are so nice at skateboarding'
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the new `.format` style string formatting with the "splat" operator:

```
>>> words = ['John', 'nice', 'skateboarding']
>>> statement = "{0} you are so {1} at {2}".format(*words)
>>> print (statement)
John you are so nice at skateboarding
```

This works even if you pass a generator:

```
>>> statement = "{0} you are so {1} at {2}".format(*(x for x in words))
>>> print (statement)
John you are so nice at skateboarding
```

Although, in this case there is no need to pass a generator when you can pass `words` directly.

One final form which I think is pretty nifty is:

```
>>> statement = "{0[0]} you are so {0[1]} at {0[2]}".format(words)
>>> print statement
John you are so nice at skateboarding
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things are wrong:

- You cannot create a generator expression without parenthesis around it. Simply putting `w for w in words` is invalid syntax for python.
- The `%` string formatting operator requires a tuple, a mapping or a single value (that is not a tuple or a mapping) as input. A generator is not a tuple, it would be seen as a single value. Even worse, the generator expression would not be iterated over:

  ```
  >>> '%s' % (w for w in words)
  '<generator object <genexpr> at 0x108a08730>'
  ```

So the following would work:

```
statement = "%s you are so %s at %s" % tuple(w for w in words)
```

Note that your generator expression doesn't actually transform the words or make a selection from the `words` list, so it is redundant here. So the simplest thing is to just cast the list to a `tuple` instead:

```
statement = "%s you are so %s at %s" % tuple(words)
```

Comment: `tuple(w for w in words)` is overkill :) see my answer.

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev: sure, but there is more to it. I perhaps submitted too early; updated now.